# Getting the text format of a cell via a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get the value of a particular cell and then paste it into my worksheet.

This value is a date, `May 2014` but is coming out as `May-14` in Excel.

How can I get the exact cell contents without Excel messing it up for me?

As when I try to then reference that cells contents to activate a worksheet, it cannot find `May-14` because it is named `May 14`.

Answer (score 1):

cell(x,y).text when your copying the value will keep the format.

if your comparing two cells either use .value if they are of different formats or .text if you want to keep formatting.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm trying to get the value of a particular cell and then paste it into my worksheet.*

If you're only concerned with the value of the cell, you can do the following to "copy" the cell's value to a new cell:

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1") = Sheets(2).Range("A1")
```

This will copy the value from one cell to another. The advantage to this method is that the value (May 2014 in this case) isn't copied to your clipboard, which will help with performance.

You can be even more specific by specifying the data type:

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1").Text = Sheets(2).Range("A1").Text
```

or

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Sheets(2).Range("A1").Value
```

or

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1").Forumla = Sheets(2).Range("A1").Formula
```